# Roslyn Unable to cast transparent proxy to type 'Roslyn.Utilities.SerializableDataStorage'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, package, roslyn

I'm having issues trying to use Microsoft Roslyn to load a Visual Studio Solution or project. Every time I run the following code:

```
Roslyn.Services.Workspace.LoadSolution(solutionFilePath);
```

I get the following error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Roslyn.Services.dll
>   Additional information: Unable to cast transparent proxy to type 'Roslyn.Utilities.SerializableDataStorage'.

The project is set to "AnyCPU" and I kill the "Roslyn.Script" process before running my code - I can't figure out what's going on.

The code seems to work when I run it in a console app but it is being run from a custom Visual Studio 13 package.

UPDATE: It turns out the problem is that that Roslyn needs to be run in x64 binaries but Visual Studio packages are on x86.

If you install the Roslyn CTP instead of using NUGet it gets around this:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/39c0226e-7063-4701-8f44-4d5419e9e82d/roslynservices-dependency-on-visualstudio-and-weird-roslynutilitiesserializabledatastorage?forum=roslyn

Comment: Since your namespace has "Roslyn.Services", this indicates you're using a very, very old CTP that's over a year and a half old. I'd highly recommend you upgrade to the [current CTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/roslyn).

Comment: So now I am using  Microsoft.CodeAnalysis -Pre. I can load the solution but all the projects fail to load. When I try load a project manually I get "Unrecognized project type".

Comment: Can you post the full stack somewhere of the exception?

Comment: The stack only contains a single line I'm afraid. Here is the demo code and the stack message: http://pastebin.com/eWb7C0Zn

Comment: Please create a new question for that issue -- this box is a bit to small for me or other people to help. Also, did you start with the "Console Application" template? You need to make sure the C# workspaces DLL is copied alongside your main workspaces DLL.